# Dealing with the multiple properties returning the new object

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, properties, itext

I've a lot of properties (around 20) in my project, which are returning the same class' new object (with the different parameters passed), therefore the code looks redundant. Is there any approach or the design pattern by which I can reduce the amount of code and perform the same operation. I did search and try but couldn't find any. My code is like:

```
        public MyClass Prop1
        {
            get
            {
                return new MyClass(0, 0);
            }
        }

        public MyClass Prop2
        {
            get
            {
                return new MyClass(0, 1);
            }
        }

        public MyClass Prop3
        {
            get
            {
                return new MyClass(1, 1);
            }
        }

        public MyClass Prop4
        {
            get
            {
                return new MyClass(2, 4);
            }
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit:**

I'm using *iTextSharp* to generate the PDF, where I've to pass the different colors, so I'm creating the properties with the colors required and using them while generating the PDF.
Here `MyClass` is the `BaseColor` class of *iTextSharp* and the parameters passed are the *RGB* values. Each property generates a different color.

Comment: why are you returning a new instance each call? perhaps you should consider caching...

Comment: can you use some collection?

Comment: Actually, new object is required to generate the new color each time by passing the RGB values.

Comment: Since these are exposed through properties, you will need an instance of the class which they reside in to get these objects.  Are you sure you do not want them to be static?

Comment: Please provide more information about the operation you are performing. It is not possible to provide helpful suggestions unless there is some context of the problem that is being solved.

Comment: For the record, per [Choosing Between Properties and Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx), you should not be using properties when `The operation returns a different result each time it is called, even if the parameters do not change.` Since you are returning a new instance each time, these are not good candidates for properties (although if you cache and return the same instance each time, it is fine). Of course, if you had a single factory method with 2 parameters, you could replace all of these properties.

Comment: I think you need to re-think the logic here.  Returning a new instance of the class on every get seems sloppy at best.

Answer (score 2):

One way to make it look cleaner would be to use the inline properties

```
public MyClass Prop1 => new MyClass(0, 0);
public MyClass Prop2 => new MyClass(0, 1);
public MyClass Prop3 => new MyClass(1, 1);
public MyClass Prop4 => new MyClass(2, 4);
```

It would make it look a bit cleaner, creating a array as suggested by @John can work but then you need to remember how many properties you have and it doesn't show in intellisense. A better option might actually be

```
public MyClass Prop1 { get; } = new MyClass(0, 0);
public MyClass Prop2 { get; } = new MyClass(0, 1);
public MyClass Prop3 { get; } = new MyClass(1, 1);
public MyClass Prop4 { get; } = new MyClass(2, 4);
```

Comment: As of now I'm going with the inline properties approached suggested by you and my code looks cleaner. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Any time you have variables or properties that contain a number in the name, that is a code smell.  See if you can replace with an array.

Example:

```
class Example
{
    static private readonly MyClass[] _myClasses;

    static public Example()
    {
        _myClasses= new MyClass[] { new MyClass(0,0),
                                    new MyClass(0,1),
                                    new MyClass(1,1),
                                    new MyClass(2,4) };
    }

    public MyClass[] Prop
    {
        get
            {
                return _myClasses;
            }
    }
}
```

Then to use the property, instead of calling

```
var c = example.Prop1;
```

use

```
var c = example.Prop[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me try to implement in this way.

Comment: This is a great way but the only problem is that when I access these properties, I don't know that which property (name), had been accessed. :-/